# Ansible way to stop a service only if it needs to be upgraded

Tags: ansible, mariadb, centos7

In an ansible playbook I want to stop MariaDB if an upgrade is needed (restart from the RPM package does not always work in my situation). I'm quite new to ansible.

I came up with this:

```
- name: "Check if MariaDB needs to be upgraded"
  shell: "yum check-update MariaDB-server|grep MariaDB|wc -l"
  register: needs_update

- name: "Stop mysql service"
  service:
  name: mysql
  state: stopped
when: needs_update.stdout == "1"
```

Is there a better way to do this then by executing a shell command? When running it I get warnings:

```
TASK [mariadb_galera : Check if MariaDB needs to be upgraded]    ******************
changed: [139.162.220.42] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "yum check-update MariaDB-server|grep MariaDB|wc -l", "delta": "0:00:00.540862", "end": "2017-03-01 13:03:34.415272", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-03-01 13:03:33.874410", "stderr": "", "stdout": "0", "stdout_lines": ["0"], "warnings": ["Consider using yum module rather than running yum"]}
 [WARNING]: Consider using yum module rather than running yum
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can hide warning with:

```
- name: "Check if MariaDB needs to be upgraded"
  shell: "yum check-update MariaDB-server|grep MariaDB|wc -l"
  args:
    warn: false
  register: needs_update
```

Or you can trick Ansible to execute `yum` task in `check_mode`:

```
- name: "Check if MariaDB needs to be upgraded (CHECK MODE!)"
  yum:
    name: MariaDB-server
    state: latest
  check_mode: yes
  register: needs_update_check

- name: "Stop mysql service"
  service:
    name: mysql
    state: stopped
  when: needs_update_check | changed
```

*Please, test this code before use.*

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The check_mode comamnd does not show up as changed while the old command does show up as changed. 

When I execute the old command it does show as upgradeable:
[root@li1383-42 my.cnf.d]# yum check-update MariaDB-server|grep MariaDB|wc -l
1

Comment: Some corner case? Just checked it with vagrant box `bento/centos-6.7 (virtualbox, 2.2.7)` and `curl` package – works as expected. I'm on ansible 2.2.1.0 (just in case).

Comment: I run  CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core), I also runansible 2.2.1.0. I am happy to report this bug somewhere but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is use a "handler"
eg something along the lines of

```
tasks:
  - name: Update db
    yum: name=MariaDB-server state=latest
    notify:
      - stop db

handlers:
  -  name: stop db  
     service: name=MariaDB-server state=stopped
```

You can specify multiple handlers if you need to do multiple things, but if you just want to restart the db, use restarted instead of stopped

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html

Comment: Don't forget to flush handlers, otherwise you'll get stopped server at the end of playbook.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. He asked to stop the service **if it needs to be upgraded**. This answer stops the service after upgrading and presumably after an automatic restart.

Comment: True @Konstantin Suvorov but it could just be miscommunication and as nobody had mentioned handlers it was worth putting in there.